# Same column multiple times in query

Tags: sql-server, sum

Question for SQL Server experts.  In the below query I would like to have an additional column which also SUMs Quantity but does so based on a different Requirement Type.  I have tried a few ideas - CASE and adding a subquery in the select list but all return far too many results.  What I would like to see is MATERIAL, MATERIAL_DESCRIPTION,SIZE_LITERAL,SUM OF QUANTITY WHEN REQUIREMENT TYPE = 'PB', SUM OF QUANTITY WHEN REQUIREMENT TYPE = '01' Not sure how to add the quantity twice on two different conditions.  Thanks in advance

```
SELECT MATERIAL, 
       MATERIAL_DESCRIPTION, 
       SIZE_LITERAL, 
       SUM(QUANTITY) AS 'SUM_FCST' 

FROM   VW_MRP_ALLOCATION

WHERE REQUIREMENT_CATEGORY = 'A60381002'

AND MATERIAL_AVAILABILITY_DATE >= GETDATE()

AND REQUIREMENT_TYPE ='PB'


GROUP BY MATERIAL, 
         MATERIAL_DESCRIPTION,
         SIZE_LITERAL

ORDER BY MATERIAL, 
         SIZE_LITERAL
```

Comment: conditional sum using case statements.  Two of them... and remove limit from where clause

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would use a `CASE` expression inside of the `SUM()`. This is conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT MATERIAL, 
       MATERIAL_DESCRIPTION, 
       SIZE_LITERAL, 
       SUM(case when REQUIREMENT_TYPE ='PB' then QUANTITY else 0 end) AS 'SUM_FCST_PB',
       SUM(case when REQUIREMENT_TYPE ='01' then QUANTITY else 0 end) AS 'SUM_FCST_01'    
FROM   VW_MRP_ALLOCATION
WHERE REQUIREMENT_CATEGORY = 'A60381002'
  AND MATERIAL_AVAILABILITY_DATE >= GETDATE()
GROUP BY MATERIAL, 
         MATERIAL_DESCRIPTION,
         SIZE_LITERAL
ORDER BY MATERIAL, 
         SIZE_LITERAL
```

Comment: brilliant - and thank you - question - if you didn't have ELSE 0 END - instead just END , would it still work?  If not why not? I appreciate the help

Comment: @user3496218 The difference would be the `else 0` would insert a zero value into the rows where nothing matched, otherwise it would just be null.  It depends on how you want it to appear - [here is a demo](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/673031).

Answer (score 1):

You can use case inside sum as below:

```
SELECT MATERIAL, 
       MATERIAL_DESCRIPTION, 
       SIZE_LITERAL, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN [Requirement_Type] = 'PB' then QUANTITY else 0 end) AS 'SUM_FCST' 

FROM   VW_MRP_ALLOCATION

WHERE REQUIREMENT_CATEGORY = 'A60381002'

AND MATERIAL_AVAILABILITY_DATE >= GETDATE()

AND REQUIREMENT_TYPE ='PB'


GROUP BY MATERIAL, 
         MATERIAL_DESCRIPTION,
         SIZE_LITERAL

ORDER BY MATERIAL, 
         SIZE_LITERAL
```